# Rehashing custom hash table using Arrays

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

After working on a custom hash table using an Array, I realised that when I resize the hash table after the max ratio of items to size is greater than 0.6, it would render my hash function useless as for the next load of hash functions after the resize would be different.

Here is my current rehash function, logically this will not work as it could potentially overwrite old values with a new hash, which would mean items would be deleted from the table.

```
private void reHash(){
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length-1; i ++){
            if(arr[i] != null){
                Pair u = (Pair) arr[i];
                put(u.key, (V) u.value); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Put is the method I use to insert. Was thinking of using a temporary array and then set the original to the temp, but this would mean changing alot of code in the table.

Any advice??
Thanks

Comment: Yes, using a temporary array is the way to go.

Comment: "but this would mean changing alot of code in the table" Surely the replacement is restricted to the rehash-when-enlarging scenario. All other methods should simply see the array reference.